# How to avoid returning a temporary object (C++)

Tags: object, memory-management, return, temporary

The code below is showing a poor example of memory management; item is never de-allocated because a temporary copy of it is returned instead.

I've been scouring programming forums on and off for weeks but haven't found a clear explanation as to how to properly return a valid instance of type Item* while allowing item to be de-allocated.
In other words, what is a better alternative to this code that accomplishes the same return value and yet allows item to be de-allocated?

```
Item* Inventory::add(const string& name)
{ 
    Item* item = new Item(name);
    ...(some other code here)...
    return item;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about `std::unique_ptr<Item>`?

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem. You've returned the only copy of the pointer to _item_ to the client—now it's the client's job to deallocate it. Just make that fact explicit in the contract/documentation/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might think everything is destroyed once it goes outside the loop, but the pointer that is returned (*and the memory that it points to*) will stay. It is transferred to the object that calls this method, and no memory is leaked.

Comment: Thanks.  Allow me to add one thing:  I don't own the client's portion of the code, so I can't deallocate item from there.  Is there another way to avoid a memory leak?

Comment: That really depends on the scope and visibility of your portion of your code. In one example of production code that I've seen, there are a number of "manager" classes which are handled by one global master manager class . User must create pointer to the master manager class. Then When user needs one of the "manager" class, they can call `new` to get pointer as usual but they should not deallocate those pointers themselves; they need only to call `delete`of the master manager pointer, and it will in turn deallocate all the existing manager classes.